# Derivation of $\frac{d}{dt}\mathbf L = I \dot{\boldsymbol \omega} = \mathbf M - \boldsymbol \omega \times \mathbf L$

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, rotational-dynamics, torque, rigid-body-dynamics

I would like to know how the above quantity is derived (Here $\mathbf{M}$ is the rate of change of angular momentum with respect to a non inertial frame).I tried looking at various sources and couldn't find a derivation. I have no idea where $\vec{\omega} \times \mathbf{L}$ came into this equation. In what cases does the $\vec{\omega} \times \mathbf{L}$ term vanish? Because if $\vec{\omega}$ were in the direction of $\mathbf{L}$ it wouldn't be rotational motion anymore? It would be of great help to me if some could point out the flaws in my logic and hand me a derivation.

Comment: To clarify, $\mathbf{M}$ is the rate of change of _angular_ momentum in a non-inertial frame, correct?

Comment: Yes it is.I have fixed it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the current form of the equation, I have to make a few assumptions about the currently-missing context:

- $\mathbf{L}$ is the angular momentum in a *fixed* frame.
- $\mathbf{M}$ refers to the rate of change of *angular* momentum in a frame that is *rotating* with angular velocity vector $\vec{\omega}$.
- The $\vec{\omega}$ in the final term of the equation is mostly unrelated to the $\omega$ in $I\dot{\omega}$. The former is the rotational velocity of the *rotating reference frame itself*, while the latter is the angular velocity of the *object* in the *fixed reference frame*. They really should have different symbols.

Given this, the transformation above is a specific example of a very general formula: for any vector $\mathbf{Q}$, its rate of change in a fixed frame and its rate of change in a frame rotating with angular velocity vector $\vec{\omega}$ are related by:

$$\left(\frac{d\mathbf{Q}}{dt}\right)_{fixed}=\left(\frac{d\mathbf{Q}}{dt}\right)_{rot}+\vec{\omega}\times\mathbf{Q}$$

A derivation of this general relation can be found in most upper-level undergraduate textbooks, and on Wikipedia as well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_reference_frame.

Comment: thanks a lot sir

Answer (score 0):

The angular momentum vector is:

$$\vec{L}=I\,\vec{\omega}$$

if you take the components of the angular velocity $\vec{\omega}$ in B-frame and the Inertial tensor $I$  also in B-Frame you get the components of the angular momentum in I-frame with this equation:
$$\vec{L}_I=R\,I_B\,\vec{\omega}_B\tag 1$$
where R is the transformation matrix between B-frame and I-frame.

the time derivative of equation (1) is:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\vec{L}_I=R\,I_B\,\vec{\dot{\omega}}_B+\dot{R}\,I_B\,\vec{\omega}_B\tag 2$$

with:

$$\dot{R}=R\,\left[\tilde{\omega}\right]_B=R\,\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 0&-\omega_{{z}}&\omega_{{y}}
\\ \omega_{{z}}&0&-\omega_{{x}}\\ 
-\omega_{{y}}&\omega_{{x}}&0\end {array} \right]_B 
$$

$\Rightarrow$ equation (2) :

$$\frac{d}{dt}\vec{L}_I=R\,I_B\,\vec{\dot{\omega}}_B+R\left[\vec{\omega}_B\times (I_B\,\vec{\omega}_B)\right]\tag 3$$

multiply equation (3) from the left with $R^T$ ($\quad R^T\,R=I_3$)

$$\underbrace{R^T\,\frac{d}{dt}\vec{L}_I}_{\vec{M}}=I_B\,\vec{\dot{\omega}}_B+\vec{\omega}_B\times \underbrace{(I_B\,\vec{\omega}_B)}_{\vec{L}_B}$$

thus :

$$\vec{M}=\left(\frac{d}{dt}\vec{L}_I\right)_B$$

---

I use this notation

- index B is body frame
- index I is inertial frame